# How to use streaming stores in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I was wondering what exactly it takes to make use of streaming/non-temporal stores with Fortran source code. Assuming the algorithm is suitable for streaming stores. Somehow I could not find a conclusive explanation, so here are my questions:

1) Is it compiler-specific?
If I understood correctly, with C source code the compiler can determine whether streaming stores are used. For example icc can make use of them given the proper optimization flags, while gcc is unable to use them.
Can gfortran use them? if so, which optimization flags are required? Or do I need ifort?

2) Do I need to change my code in order to use them? Or to at least help the compiler figuring out what to do. If so, what would that look like? For example for a simple copy:

```
b(:) = a(:)
```

Comment: So far it seems to be compiler specific. I don't think gfortran has it. But Intel does. https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-qopt-streaming-stores-qopt-streaming-stores

Comment: And see option comparisons (which show gnu missing the streaming stores options) here: https://doku.lrz.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31065076

Comment: Almost everything about the platform that Fortran runs on is compiler-specific, the language standard scarcely recognises the existence of computers let alone such concepts as streaming stores.  And probably best not to think that `b(:) = a(:)` is a simple copy.

Comment: @Mark: What is it then? And what IS a copy if such a thing exists?

Comment: The *lhs* of the expression is an *array section* and the code will only work if both `a` and `b` have the same number of elements.  It's a copy alright, but the subtleties of using array sections make it not simple.

Comment: I can't say I really get that. Same size and shape were implied, obviously.